# Update from version 3.1.1 to version 4.1.3

Tags: pimcore

Trying to do a live update from 3.1.1 to 4.1.3

It goes trough the whole process, loading from 0 to 100% says update complete! and ask me to reload Pimcore.

After I reloaded the page it's still says 3.1.1 in the bottom right corner, new version available. nothing seem to changed. Also looking at the files no files seem to have been changed except for some database logs.

We get these warnings while running the update:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /pimcore/lib/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php on line 230
Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /pimcore/lib/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php on line 230
Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://update.pimcore.org:443 (Unknown error) in /pimcore/lib/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php on line 230
```

We are running Pimcore on a site that previously where upgraded programmatically from version 1.4.5 to 3.1.1 (by replacing the pimcore folder and running the database-upgrades manually).

All our folders are write-protected except for `pimcore/` and `website/var`

Some of the folders inside `website/var/` and the `pimcore/` are moved outside public directory and the startup constants to these directories are modified in our index.php.

Need some advice on how to fix the upgrade...

Thanks
/J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all of the system requirements met?
https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE4/System+Requirements
https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE4/Update+from+Version+3.x+to+Version+4

You probably need to add **OpenSSL extension** to the PHP.

Comment: Solved it by downloading CA certificates from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and setting the openssl.cafile parameter to its path.